# How to add separator between table data text in Beautifulsoup?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

How can I get `print(table.text)` in `Beautiful Soup` to add a space or comma between each text string?

When I use this(my preferred method):

```
table =soup.find('table')
print(table.text)
```

each 'td' value runs into the next and looks like this and messes up the table structure with each value running into the next:

```
←Round: 1 Venue: M.C.G. Date: Wed, 16-Mar-2022 7:10 PM (6:10 PM) Attendance: 58002→Melbourne4.5.296.6.4210.8.6814.13.97Western Bulldogs2.2.148.3.518.5.5311.5.71Qrt marginME by 15WB by 9ME by 15ME by 26Qrt scoresME 29-14WB 37-13ME 26-2ME 29-18Field umpiresJohn Howorth (43), Rob Findlay (280), Jacob Mollison (283)
```

If I use this:

```
for td in table:
  td = td.find_all('td')
  row = [i.get_text() for i in td]
  print(row)
```

I get a much more readable result however there is the added `'` between values and everything is separated into individual rows with the `[]` brackets means I need additional formatting for the next stage

```
['Melbourne', '4.5.29', '6.6.42', '10.8.68', '14.13.97']
['Western Bulldogs', '2.2.14', '8.3.51', '8.5.53', '11.5.71']
['Qrt margin', 'ME by 15', 'WB by 9', 'ME by 15', 'ME by 26']
['Qrt scores', 'ME 29-14', 'WB 37-13', 'ME 26-2', 'ME 29-18']
['Field umpires', 'John Howorth (43), Rob Findlay (280), Jacob Mollison (283)']
```

My preference is the first version with spacing or other delimiter between `td` values all in the same line as it is formatted better for the new table I wish to create from multiple sources of this data

Comment: If you have the list, then you can join the elements with a space

`row = ' '.join([i.get_text() for i in td])`

Answer (score 0):

*As of Beautiful Soup version 4.10.0, you can call [get_text()](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#get-text), .strings, or .stripped_strings on a NavigableString object. It will either return the object itself, or nothing, so the only reason to do this is when you’re iterating over a mixed list.*

You could separate your strings in [`get_text()`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#get-text) with additional separator of your choice as parameter:

```
[row.get_text("|", strip=True) for row in soup.select('table tr')]
```

or use `stripped_strings` to get lists:

```
[list(row.stripped_strings) for row in soup.select('table tr')]
```

In case of just printing results:

```
for row in soup.select('table tr'):
    print(row.get_text("|", strip=True))
```

Comment: This works perfectly to improve the readability of my 2nd method. The resulting layout of data from `print(table.text)` is better for me. How can I insert a `space` etc between each field using this method?

Comment: Read my answer again or the link in the documentation, if in doubt just replace the current separator. Regardless of this, I think the procedure from the OP is only suitable for further processing to a limited extent; rather, it should be transferred to a data structure that is somewhat more consistent.